# HTTP request to a web application using cloudflare access

Tags: php, apache, http, https, cloudflare

We use cloudflare access to make web applications on the local server available to external users.
In that case, http requests from the external api will pass through the cloudflare proxy once, but will they be blocked at that time?

I would like to use the switchbot api's webhook, but I am not receiving any notification. I would like to make this happen.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please add more details to your question, and give some examples, what you have already tried?

Comment: I am using cloudflare to publish php web pages created on a local server, and I want to use the webhook feature of the switchbot api.
For example, I would like to receive notifications when the temperature of the meter changes.
I have already registered a webhook based on the github documentation, but I don't receive any notifications.
Perhaps there is a function in cloudflare that prevents http requests from the switchbot api, but I have not been able to confirm this.

Comment: Please add the details to your question. Read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to write a good question on stack overflow.

Comment: Please focus on a specific problem. This forum is not to get explanations that can be found in a related documentation. If you have fundamental lack of knowledge, this is nothing you can get help with here.